# I get an error in IntelliJ when running a Glassfish server. It is a long error and I don't know how to start searching for a solution

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, payara, java-ee-8

There is only one servlet and I didn't change anything to the configurations as far as I know. This is the whole error log output.

```
[2020-05-17T15:19:19.5

94+0200] [Payara 5.201] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=126 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1589721559594] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while deploying the app [HelloWorld2]]]

[2020-05-17T15:19:19.595+0200] [Payara 5.201] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=126 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1589721559595] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: file:/D:/Libraries/Documents/School/Industriëel%20ingenieur%20(2019-2020)/2de%20Semester/Distributed%20applications/Installatie/Workspace/payara-5.201/payara5/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_4_0.xsd; lineNumber: 281; columnNumber: 47; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [HelloWorld2].  src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'javaee:web-commonType' to a(n) 'group' component.
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1062)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployers(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1030)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4253)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4236)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1790)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDGroupTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDGroupTraverser.java:80)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractParticleTraverser.traverseSeqChoice(XSDAbstractParticleTraverser.java:232)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractParticleTraverser.traverseChoice(XSDAbstractParticleTraverser.java:184)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.processComplexContent(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:1053)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexTypeDecl(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:335)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:191)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1938)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1825)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(XSDElementTraverser.java:405)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDElementTraverser.java:242)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.java:1482)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:662)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:617)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2710)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2069)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:829)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3063)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:836)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:324)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:312)
    ... 51 more
]]

[2020-05-17T15:19:19.667+0200] [Payara 5.201] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=126 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1589721559667] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while deploying the app [HelloWorld2] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: file:/D:/Libraries/Documents/School/Industriëel%20ingenieur%20(2019-2020)/2de%20Semester/Distributed%20applications/Installatie/Workspace/payara-5.201/payara5/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_4_0.xsd; lineNumber: 281; columnNumber: 47; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [HelloWorld2].  src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'javaee:web-commonType' to a(n) 'group' component.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: file:/D:/Libraries/Documents/School/Industriëel%20ingenieur%20(2019-2020)/2de%20Semester/Distributed%20applications/Installatie/Workspace/payara-5.201/payara5/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_4_0.xsd; lineNumber: 281; columnNumber: 47; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [HelloWorld2].  src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'javaee:web-commonType' to a(n) 'group' component.
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:322)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:239)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:709)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:391)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1062)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployers(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1030)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4253)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4236)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1790)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDGroupTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDGroupTraverser.java:80)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractParticleTraverser.traverseSeqChoice(XSDAbstractParticleTraverser.java:232)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractParticleTraverser.traverseChoice(XSDAbstractParticleTraverser.java:184)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.processComplexContent(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:1053)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexTypeDecl(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:335)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:191)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1938)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1825)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(XSDElementTraverser.java:405)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDElementTraverser.java:242)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.java:1482)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:662)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:617)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2710)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2069)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:829)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3063)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:836)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:324)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:312)
    ... 51 more
]]
```

There were only a few websites I could find that mentioned a similar problem, but they all ended with a "solved", without an answer to the question.
I am working with java SDK 11

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, I chose the wrong folder as a package when making the project.